# Does Android not localise default folder names?

Tags: localization

I suppose I expected Android to handle this like Linux, but it seems the default folder names must stay in English.  Is this just the Irish-language locale on Samsung or does it work that way for other languages?

Is there a way to let the OS know what my localised folders are?

**Edit:** By default folders, I mean the user folders called *Downloads*, *Music*, *Pictures*, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. By "*default folders*", did you mean something like "Alarms", "DCIM", "Music", "Notifications", "Pictures", "Ringtones", etc.?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No those folders are never localized.